# Зачем наследовать от Frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

помогите пожалуйста разобраться в одном важном для меня вопросе

принято создавать интерфейсы через классы. это делается для того чтобы:

- можно было при желании удобным
     образом вставить готовый интерфейс в
     определённое место программы.
- можно было клонировать
     функциональность, не дублируя код
- код интерфейса находился в
     определённом контексте(то есть
     отсутствовали бы конфликты
     переменных)

НО что я никак не могу понять, так это зачем класс нужно наследовать от Frame. вот например распространённый шаблон:

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox
class Quitter(tkinter.Frame):                          
    def __init__(self, parent=None):          
        tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.pack()
        widget = tkinter.Button(self, text='Quit', command=self.quit)
        widget.pack(side='left', expand='yes', fill=tkinter.BOTH)
    def quit(self):
        ans = tkinter.messagebox.askokcancel('Verify exit', "Really quit?")
        if ans: tkinter.Frame.quit(self)
if __name__ == '__main__':  Quitter().mainloop()
```

Comment: Ну это, вероятно, зависит от того, что Вы от класса хотите. Судя по всему, Вы немного смешиваете мягкое с тёплым.

И ещё. Если Вы обсуждаете tkinter (или tcl/tk) -- это одно. Если какие-то сакральные мудрости ООП -- совсем другое. И, поэтому, что Вы имеете в виду, говоря "интерфейс" -- не совсем понятно.

Comment: ну в общем вы правы. дело в том, что сам толком не знаю что хочу спросить. это пример из книжки небезызвестного Лутца. он всегда предлагает интерфейсы tkinter делать подобным образом, но нигде не объясняет зачем. предполагаю, что создаваемый интерфейс(кнопочки, модальные окна и т.д.) что-то там наследуют  важное из класса Frame. но это что-то нигде у лутца не применяется. поэтому это меня вводит в ступор

Comment: @Sergey Kalinin Ну наследует то, что у Frame есть. Зачем -- чтобы дополнительную функциональность не показывать в тексте, а скомпоновать в описании/реализации класса. А что там во Frame -- смотрите книгу, смотрите объект (функцию dir() вроде никто не запрещал). Корреляция с tcl/tk, по которой ресурсов полно, вполне проста, хотя несколько затрудняется тем, что не все имена из tcl допустимы в python, поэтому в tkinter они называются похоже, но немного иначе.

Answer (score 1):

Как мне представляется, данный пример описывает класс представляющий настройку универсальной кнопки Выхода Quit, т. е. это виджет, значит чтобы отобразиться в главном окне или другом виджете (Frame? Toplevel) он должен быть виджетом , т.е. наследовать от виджета. Как мне кажется Frame Лутц берёт как очевидный тип виджета где можно разместить кнопку.

Я ради интереса изменил этот пример и унаследовал от кнопки ( Button ), вроде работает :)  (python3.4 tkinter):

```
from tkinter import *                          # get widget classes
from tkinter.messagebox import askokcancel     # get canned std dialog

class Quitter1(Button):                          # subclass our GUI
    def __init__(self, master):           # constructor method
        Button.__init__(self, master)
        widget = Button(master, text='Quit', command=self.quit1)
        widget.pack(side=LEFT, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
        self.P = master

    def quit1(self):
        ans = askokcancel('Verify exit', "Really quit?")
        if ans:
            self.P.quit()
            self.P.destroy()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    Q = Quitter1(root)
    Q.mainloop()
```